# why is the color of my hat blue and not orange?

Tags: materials, 3d-view

I made the hat by copying some vertices from the head and separating the mesh. Then i made the material single user and changed it to orange.

But still...my hat is not orange so i made some stupid mistake...

[image]

blend file:

[image]

and yes, i know and i want to be in viewport shading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not in the material view, so that Viewport display color is used:

[image]